# Learning code at school currently doing one of my exercises and can't seem to fix this

Tags: c#

Currently working on an exercise to create a shopping app, currently working on the check out method of the program where the user selects their payment type through a simple console based program that uses numerical selections. Getting error 
CS0029 "cannot implicitly convert type int to string"

In the context of the code "input" Is the console.readline(); that the user inputs when asked for their selection.

```
    public void UserInformation()
    {
        string input = "";


        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your Name");
        string userName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your address");
        Console.Write(">");
        string userAddress = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please Select payment type");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Debit");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Credit");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Cash on delivery");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write(">");

         if (input = 1)// gives error CS0029 "cannot implicitly convert 
                                                     type int to string"
         {
            //Debit
            Console.WriteLine($"Your total is {total}");
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your Debit card Number");
            string userDebit = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write(">");
         }
        else
        if (input = 2)
        {
            //Credit
            Console.WriteLine($"Your total is {total}");
            Console.WriteLine("Please select card type");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Visa");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Mastercard");
            Console.WriteLine("3. American Express");
            string userCredit = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write(">");
        }
```

Comment: First: comparing objects should be done with `==`, not `=`, as the latter is an **assignment**, not a **comparison**. Second: Your inout surely is something like `"1"`, not just `1`. You have to explicetly convert that input to a number, e.g. by using `Convert.ToInt32` or `int.Parse`.

Comment: You need to convert the string to an int and you must use `==` instead of `=` in `if` condition. So try: `int.TryParse(input, out var value); if (value == 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that your IF statements are wrong.  If you are comparing a string "Input" to 2.  this will need to be done like this:

```
 if (input == "2")
```

That was you are Explicitly comparing it to a string, not an Int